# ASP.NET MVC 5 and Bootstrap 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

Been looking around the nets for a bit more information but couldn't find much.

So I have created a new MVC 5 Project in `VS 2013 RC` which comes pre-installed with `bootstrap 2.3.1`

Everything works like a charm, but since `Bootstrap 3` is out (and me wanting to use the `LESS` version and not `pre-compiled CSS`) I removed `bootstrap 2.3.1` from `NuGet` and installed `Bootstrap LESS`.

I know the folder structure is slightly different, but I have edited my `BundleConfig` to accommodate for that. Everything seems to compile fine, all the JS are there, but when trying to view the web page it looks messed up.

Does `Bootstrap 3` have completely different `HTML` template (i.e. do I need to change `_Layout` ?) or should the `_Layout` that came with `2.3.1` work with `v3` as well?

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: make sure you mark questions as answered otherwise you may struggle to get people to spend time answering future questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some differences between `Bootstrap 3` and `Bootstrap 2.3.1`.

I have made some changes to my `_Layout` to make it more `Bootstrap 3` friendly.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex5-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex5-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Also bear in mind that the bootstrap asp validation will need some tweaking as it relies on the old html structure.

Comment: Great.. what I was looking for! Also found this [link](http://www.ghislainproulx.net/Blog/2013/09/using-bootstrap-3-with-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-mvc-template)

How would one go about doing that @RyanMcDonough

Comment: Basically follow that guide, it includes updates to the validation by the looks of things.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 3 changed things around and now requires different html here and there.
You can easily confirm that by looking at their [documentation pages](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to keep in mind; if you are using unobtrusive validation, you will need to update the package to get client side validation working. 
**Update-Package Microsoft.Jquery.Unobtrusive.Validation** 
Otherwise, your page will post to validate.