# ASP.NET MVC4 + Bootstrap 3 How to apply a different theme?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying the new Visual Studio Version, which comes with the built-in Bootstrap Template. Since I wanted to use Bootstrap 3, I upgraded all files according to a helpful thread: [ASP.NET MVC 5 and Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811574/asp-net-mvc-5-and-bootstrap-3)
This works fine, but I have trouble to apply a different Theme. 
As far as I understand, I can simply replace the bootstrap.css with a different theme and the theme "should" work (I deduced this from http://bootswatch.com/) - but for me the Thema always stays at the ASP.NET default, which I doesn't like.
So: How can I change the damned theme? Ideally, I want to use: http://bootswatch.com/cerulean/
Thank you very much.

Comment: What about `href='/css/@userthemefolder/style.css'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap's css comes in 2 files: bootstrap.css and bootstrap-theme.css.
I didn't see how it is implemented in mvc5 template, but I'm pretty sure it is done using bundles. So, you got to check the bundles.cs file and replace bootstrap-theme.css there with theme of your choice.

Comment: In the MVC 5 template, there are both files. The problem is: the Cerulean "download" contains only the bootstrap.css, there is no "theme" :(

Comment: Ah ok, I think I have figured it out: Your way works, but the Theme I selected for me (Cerulean) doesn't look as intended...

Comment: Well then, i guess, you should just delete theme from bundle.

Comment: These are the steps suggested by Microsoft: http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#bootstrap